# Attach varriable to a api object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I get multiple objects from a `REST API`.

I get the data via `AJAX` like this:

```
var APICaller = (function () {
    let endpoint = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";

    function api_call(method, url, data, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: method,
            data: data,
            success: callback
        });
    }

    function get_users(callback) {
        let method = "GET";
        let url = endpoint + "users";
        let data = {};
        api_call(method, url, data, callback);
    }

    return {
        get_users: get_users,
    };
})();
```

I am rolling 3 dices, and the total values of these 3 dices should be attached to each user so i can order the "scoreboard" after the total value.
I wonder if there is any way to attach the variable `totalamount` to every user?

Thanks in advace!

EDIT:

Currently i am getting all the users from the api.

This is the rest of my code withing this topic:

```
var Game = (function () {
    var dice_total;
    //Function for when the dice rolls.
    function roll_dice() {
        var value1 = $(".val1");
        var value2 = $(".val2");
        var value3 = $(".val3");
        var v1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var v2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var v3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

        value1.html(v1);
        value2.html(v2);
        value3.html(v3);

        dice_total = v1 + v2 + v3;
    }

    return {
        roll_dice: roll_dice
    };
})();

var EventHandlers = (function () {
    function init() {
        var currentPlayer;
        APICaller.get_users(on_get_users_success);

        function on_get_users_success(response) {
            //For each user in the API
            $.each(response, function (i, user) {
                $("#my-list").append('<li class="list-li"><a class="list-a">' + user.name + '</a></li>');
                //Create the divs and p tags 
                $("#dice_value").append('<div class="val_div"> <p class="val1"></p> <p class="val2"></p> <p class="val3"></p></div>');
            });
            //change information
            $("#info-txt").text("Välj en spelare!");
        }
        // On klick on a user make klicked user your own player.
        $("#my-list").on('click', '.list-a', function () {
            currentPlayer = this.text;

            $("#info-txt").text("Tryck på spela knappen för att börja spelet!");
            $("#currentPlayer-div").animate({
                height: '300px',
                opacity: '1'
            });
            $("#currentPlayer-h3").text(currentPlayer);

        });
        // On klick of the play button
        $("#startGame-button").click(function () {

            $().animate();
            $("#currentPlayer-div").animate({
                height: '150px'
            });
            $("#startGame-button").animate({
                opacity: '0'
            });
            $("#dice_value").animate({
                opacity: '1'
            });
            Game.roll_dice();
        });

        // $(".button-to-hide").click(function (){
        //     $(this).hide();
        // });

        // $("#show-all-buttons").click(function (){
        //     $(".button-to-hide").show();
        // });

        // $("#btn-edit-text").click(function (){
        //     var value = $("#my-input").val();
        //     $("p").html(value);
        // });

    }

    return {
        init: init,
    }

})();
var DocumentEdit = (function () {

    return {

    }
})();
$(document).ready(function () {
    EventHandlers.init();
});
```

Hope that describes it.

Comment: I'm a little confused. What does your API call give you back, and what is the callback you're passing in?

Comment: Check the update, hope that describes it :) @RobinZigmond

Comment: thanks @luddep - that gives more detail, but I'm still confused

So the API call gives you back some sort of array of user objects - but all you are using from these is their `name` property? Do you not get something else? And what is it about a user that makes them appear in the results of the API call?

Sounds like you want to grab these users, use the `Game,roll_dice` method on them, and store their result? Sounds simple enough - just alter the callback so that it calls this function on each user, and then stores the result somewhere.

Comment: And one technical point - your `dice_total` can't actually be accessed from outside the closure, I think you need to include it as a property of the returned object.

Comment: Okey thank you for the help! I cant really figure out how to write that code, if I understand it correctly :) @RobinZigmond

Comment: But yeah i only print out the names. What do you mean with **what is it about a user that makes them appear in the results of the API call?** :) @RobinZigmond

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179941/discussion-between-robin-zigmond-and-luddep).